# Magnolia "Page Aware" Caching

Tags: caching, magnolia

I am using Magnolia v5.7.1 and just configured the [advanced cache module for site aware caching](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Advanced+Cache+Policies+module). Before that, the default behavior was to flush all caches in case of any (activation, import, edit) in a workspace. Using the advanced cache module, if any content on a specific site is changed, only the corresponding caches are flushed. So far, so good.

Now, let's say pages A and B are cached. If page A is changed, this will flush the cache for page A **and** B (as long as both pages are on the same site). I am wondering if there is a good reason that the default behavior isn't the following: If page A is changed, **only** the cache for page A gets flushed.

I know it's possible to implement my own `FlushPolicy`, however, this seems to be a difficult task and perhaps I miss a good reason why "page aware" caching can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good reason to flush all is that change in one page might affect others. It is quite common to eg. generate menu from page strucuture, thus renaming one page would affect all pages that show menu. Or eg. have teaser component in a page that will take abstract text and image from the page it is teasing. And so on. In short, without calculating dependency graph there is no way for system to know which pages rendering might be affected by which other page changes. And in some cases it can be near impossible to know. Imagine event calendar page, with subpages for each event. And calendar being composed by query that searches for all events in current month. Since dynamic query is involved, calculating dependency graph just gets even more complicated.
That said it would still be possible to calculate dependencies and flush only affected pages, but in reality, for most cases, effort (cpu time) to calculate such graph is bigger than simply flushing all and re-rendering the pages as rendering is cheap (except special cases). On top of that it's also much faster to drop all items in the cache than retrieving them one by one and flushing only those that need to be flushed.

TLDR; For majority of the websites, it's not worth the effort to try to do very smart page cache management as costs outweigh the benefits w/o really affecting the performance.